# Build a collider around a gizmos line

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

As the title suggests, the idea is to build meshes between one sphere and another, make the meshes transparent by disabling its mesh renderer or by setting alpha color to zero. At present, because everything works, I have to assign a new layer to all the meshes because they are not parallel on the floor but according to the direction they can be oblique. In this case the RayCast would not see the part of the mesh hidden by the plane. Using the layer on RayCast I get the collider on the entire surface of the mesh. But I wonder if there is no way to set the 4 Vector3 that I pass to create the mesh so that it is parallel to the plane.
To find the 4 vertices of the mesh I used a script created to draw more parallel Gizmos lines to get a greater thickness. Once I have the 4 vertices it is easy to create a mesh. I also tried using linerenderer setting startWidth and endWidth [to get a line with apparently parallel edges in Game View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56188947/draw-cylinders-between-spheres-keeping-the-same-dimension-to-have-a-collider/56192014?noredirect=1#comment99010556_56192014). It behaves in the same way. Furthermore the BakeMesh method of linerenderer is available only for very recent versions of Unity.
This is an image of the result, I have enlarged the mesh so that its inclination is clearly visible

[image]

As you can see only the selected line, which is perfectly perpendicular in Game View, rests on the plane.

This is the code, I find the four vector3 to the left and to the right of the central position of the sphere and I store them in a list:

```
Vector3 p1 = sphere1.transform.position;
Vector3 p2 = sphere2.transform.position;
Vector3 scp1 = cam.WorldToScreenPoint(p1);
Vector3 scp2 = cam.WorldToScreenPoint(p2);
Vector3 v1 = (scp2 - scp1).normalized;
Vector3 n = Vector3.Cross(v1, Vector3.forward);
Vector3 newVert;
Vector3 o = 6f * n * 3 * (0f / 3 - 0.5f);
newVert = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(scp1 + o);
listVerts.Add(newVert );
newVert = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(scp2 + o);
listVerts.Add(newVert );
o = 6f * n * 3 * (1 - 0.5f);
newVert = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(scp2 + o);
listVerts.Add(newVert );
newVert = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(scp1 + o);
listVerts.Add(newVert );
```

Then I pass the list to a function that creates the mesh.
What do I have to work on to ensure that the meshes are all resting on the floor?
Is there a better way to get points parallel to the center of the sphere?

Comment: In the question it sounded like you just wanted to make a mesh for collision (raycast) purposes, but in the comment of my answer, you are concerned with what it looks like? Yet in your question here you explain that you are going to make it invisible anyway. Your objective here is still very unclear to me.

Comment: I'm sorry, it could be my bad English. The aim is precisely to create a collider around the Gizmos line. The spheres are the vertices of a main mesh and by moving the spheres I model it. The collider is used to insert new spheres (vertices) at the point of the click. However by placing the invisible meshes (colliders) parallel to  the work plane some of them (especially the horizontal ones), due to the rotation of the camera, are no longer visible (at the moment I leave them visible for testing). This means that even the RayCast does not see them or in other cases (oblique lines) [...continue]

Comment: the collider decreases its thickness. Only the vertical lines show the collider of the defined width. If, on the other hand, I leave the mesh-colliders with their inclination as you can see in the image I posted they are always facing the camera and the RayCast hits them entirely. I don't know if I managed to explain myself well and my approach could also be improved. If I'm not seeing something, I'd appreciate it if you let me know.

Comment: If you have a low number of spheres, you might be able to iterate between every pair of spheres, and then figure out the shortest distance between the mouse ray cast and the line, and where on the line that is. You do that for every line between 2 spheres and find out which one has the shortest distance. Then for the one with the shortest distance, you create the ball at the closest point on that line (if it is in fact close at all)  Look at https://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/3d_Math_functions and search for "ClosestPointsOnTwoLines" for some help. keep in mind [...continue]

Comment: that the linked code above is for infinite lines, so you will want to make sure to ignore situations where the closest points are beyond the spheres and/or behind the camera.

Comment: Thanks, yes, before deciding to use colliders I had thought of this solution, I did some tests and they worked (although they still needed a lot of controls). But then I thought that the script could require too many resources to iterate for each pair of spheres. In some cases you could have only one mesh with a few vertices, in other cases more meshes with many vertices. A simple rectangle with 4 triangles (double-sided) is quickly created on the fly and with the name I assign to it I can easily trace the two spheres that "contain" it. I will do performance tests for both scripts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193668/discussion-between-ruzihm-and-valter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to just overwrite the `y` component of each vertex with the y component of the bottom of the sphere it's next to.

```
// I recall from your previous question that you have a formula to 
// calculate the scale / radius directly but it's not in the question, 
// so here's a way to estimate it:

float sphere1Radius = p1.transform.lossyScale.x / 2f; 
float sphere2Radius = p2.transform.lossyScale.x / 2f

float sphere1BottomY = p1.y - sphere1Radius;
float sphere2BottomY = p2.y - sphere2Radius;

newVert = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(scp1 + o);
newVert.y = sphere1BottomY  
listVerts.Add(newVert );

newVert = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(scp2 + o);
newVert.y = sphere2BottomY 
listVerts.Add(newVert );

o = 6f * n * 3 * (1 - 0.5f);
newVert = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(scp2 + o);
newVert.y = sphere2BottomY
listVerts.Add(newVert );

newVert = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(scp1 + o);
newVert.y = sphere1BottomY 
listVerts.Add(newVert );
```

Comment: @ Ruzihm Thanks, your indications are correct and this way the meshes are parallel to the plane. However, this change allowed me to understand that I made a wrong consideration. By rotating the meshes, they, according to their direction, no longer appear in Game View as if they were the outline of the Gizmos line and in some cases they are not even visible anymore. This of course because of the perspective. I tried to move them to the center and above the spheres but it is now clear that it is their rotation that allows us to see them as rectangles in Game View so as to have [...continue]

Comment: the same thickness both on the left and on the right of the Gizmos line. I truly believe that the only solution is to use a Ray Cast on their personal Layer to collide even with the part that is covered by the plan. If anyone has suggestions, it's welcome, it's a pretty popular topic in the forums.